# Create a dictionary from another dictionary expanded using LINQ

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
public class FamilyAndSubForProduct
{
    public string MainFamily { get; set; }
    public string Feature { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public List<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

I have function that return `List<FamilyAndSubForProduct>` and from this i need to create a dictionary. For now i have only this:

```
var newDict = myFamily.Select(x => new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>()
    {
        {
            x.MainFamily, new Dictionary<string,string>()
            {
                {x.Synonyms.Where(y => y == x.Feature), x.Feature}
            }
        }
    }).ToDictionary();
```

My new dictionary need to save `MainFamily` and for this `MainFamily` other `Features` and `Synonyms` (if have)

For example `myFamily` have:

```
{
    MainFamily = productfamily
    Feature = productfeature
    Group = ""
    Synonyms = null
},
{
    MainFamily = productfamily
    Feature = productfeature1
    Group = ""
    Synonyms = productfeature1synonym, productfeature1synonm2
}
```

In result i need dictionary like this:

```
{productfamily -> {productfeature, productfeature},
               -> {productfeature1, productfeature1},
               -> {productfeature1synonym, productfeature1},
               -> {productfeature1synonym2, productfeature1}
}
```

My formula doesn't work and i want to learn how to do that. Thanks for reply

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second side of the dictionary? Why have productfeature twice?

Comment: second string in second Dictionary is result. If found synonym i need to return only main feature. If productfeature doesn't have synonyms, that show first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ for that like this:

```
var myFamily = new List<FamilyAndSubForProduct>
{
    new FamilyAndSubForProduct
    {
        MainFamily = "productfamily",
        Feature = "productfeature",
        Group = "",
        Synonyms = null
    },
    new FamilyAndSubForProduct
    {
        MainFamily = "productfamily",
        Feature = "productfeature1",
        Group = "",
        Synonyms = new List<string> { "productfeature1synonym", "productfeature1synonm2" }
    }
};
var dict = myFamily.GroupBy(f => f.MainFamily).ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
    g => g.SelectMany(f => 
        Enumerable.Repeat(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(f.Feature, f.Feature), 1)
        .Concat(f.Synonyms != null ?
            f.Synonyms.Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, f.Feature)) :
            Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, string>>())
        ).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value)
);
```

What it does is first grouping the records by `MainFamily` to produce the keys for your outer dictionary, then for each of the items in the group, it creates 2 sets - one with single {`Feature`, `Feature`} item and optionally a second with record {`Synonym`, `Feature`} for each item in the `Synonyms`, merges those 2 sets together and produces the inner dictionary.

**EDIT:** Same can be accomplished with the even shorter

```
var dict = myFamily.GroupBy(f => f.MainFamily).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g
    .SelectMany(f => Enumerable.Repeat(f.Feature, 1).Concat(f.Synonyms ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
    .ToDictionary(s => s, s => f.Feature)));
```